# Send the structure along with message, accumulate the message and resend to neighbour in Veins

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, omnet++

I would like to accumulate a kind of trust value (say 'theta=' which is between 0.5 to 1) from all the neighbor nodes along with the message and then send to other nodes the accumulated message and the trust value. Also need to make a log file of those values in .txt file or cvs format.
 the structure may be like:

```
struct knownVehicle {
               int id;
               std::string vType;
               double theta=0.5;
               simtime_t lastSeenAt;
                      };

void TraCITestApp::onData(EWaveShortMessage* wsm) {
findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
annotations->scheduleErase(1, annotations->drawLine(wsm->getSenderPos(), mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()), "blue"));
   if (mobility->getRoadId()[0] != ':') traciVehicle->changeRoute("-39539626", 9999);
      if (sentMessage){

    //Added for Knownvehicle receiving
          knownVehicle &recveh = wsm->getKnownVeh();
              double rectheta = recveh.theta;
              // process other fields of recveh
              delete &recveh; // remember to remove dynamically created object

          // check if new warning
         bool isNewWarning = true;
         for (map<long,WaveShortMessages>::iterator i = receivedWarningMessageMap.begin(); i != receivedWarningMessageMap.end(); ++i) {
           WaveShortMessage* msg = i->second[0];
           if (msg->getTreeId() == wsm->getTreeId())
               isNewWarning = false;
         }
         // add warning message to received messages storage
           receivedWarningMessageMap[wsm->getTreeId()].push_back(wsm->dup());
           std::ofstream logFile;
           logFile.open("log.txt", std::ios_base::app); // if exist it will be overwritten if added "std::ios_base::app" Appends
           std::stringstream ss;
           std::cout<<"MyID="<<getMyID()<<";"<< "Sender Id="<< wsm->getSenderAddress()<<endl;
          std::cout << "Accumulated receivedWarningMessageMap="<<wsm->dup() << std::endl;
          logFile <<"MyID="<<getMyID()<< "Sender Id="<< wsm->getSenderAddress()<<endl;

           for (auto it = receivedWarningMessageMap.begin(); it != receivedWarningMessageMap.end(); ++it) {
               ss << "id=" << static_cast<int>(it->first) << "; wsms Contents=";
               for (auto it2 : it->second) {
                   ss << it2 << "; ";
                      }
               }
               ss << endl;

 std::cout<<"MyID="<<getMyID()<<";"<< "Sender Id="<< wsm->getSenderAddress()<<endl;
           std::cout << "Accumulated receivedWarningMessageMap="<<wsm->dup() << std::endl;
           logFile <<"MyID="<<getMyID()<< "Sender Id="<< wsm->getSenderAddress()<<endl;
           logFile << "====Accumulated receivedWarningMessageMap (wsm->dup())=>"<<wsm->dup() <<"====\n"<< std::endl;
           logFile << ss.str();
           logFile <<"======================\n" <<endl;
         //  logFile.close();


 void TraCITestApp::sendMessage1(double theta)
{
        sentMessage = true;
t_channel channel = dataOnSch ? type_SCH : type_CCH;
EWaveShortMessage* wsm = prepareWSM("data", dataLengthBits, channel,  dataPriority, -1,2);
knownVehicle * veh = new knownVehicle();
veh->theta = 0.5;

// set other fields...
WaveShortMessage * packet = new WaveShortMessage();

packet->setKnownVeh(*veh);  // I got error here ...

// and now packet is ready to send, using send() OMNeT++ method
 sendWSM(wsm);
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer this question. Please elaborate on the purpose of these 'trust' values, what these messages are and where they're going. Perhaps a small example input and output.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and sorry for not enough information as well as for my poor english...

Comment: Do you want to send whole `knownVehicle` structure, or only `theta` value or another structure? And second issue: *when* a node should send the message with accumulated value?

Comment: Hello Jerzy D, for my current situation, sending theta works but in future I may need to send the whole structure as well. Is it possible if that you can give solution for both.  I am implementing the sending wsm message in     void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm)  in veins. So,  the broadcasting message is sent by vehicles in range of accident and after the accident has occured.

Comment: hi Jerzy, may be it is possible to send the trust value theta from within the "waveshortmessage.msg" by adding additional fields in .msg. But I also need to update the theta value after accumulating by each vehicle as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to **send** an instance of `knownVehicle` using `WaveShortMessage` do the following modification of `WaveShortMessage.msg`:

```
// file: /veins/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg
cplusplus {{
#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
struct knownVehicle {
  int id;
  std::string vType;
  double theta;
  simtime_t lastSeenAt;
};
}}

class noncobject knownVehicle;
class noncobject Coord;

packet WaveShortMessage {
//Version of the Wave Short Message
int wsmVersion = 0;
// ...
knownVehicle knownVeh;
}
```

When you want to send `WaveShortMessage` with a `knownVehicle` object use the following code:

```
// add include:
// #include "WaveShortMessage_m.h"

knownVehicle * veh = new knownVehicle();
veh->theta = 0.5;
veh->id = 15;
// set other fields...
WaveShortMessage * packet = new WaveShortMessage();
packet->setKnownVeh(*veh);
// and now packet is ready to send, using send() OMNeT++ method
```

**Receiving** a `WaveShortMessage`:

```
void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
    knownVehicle & recveh = wsm->getKnownVeh();
    double rectheta = recveh.theta;
    // process other fields of recveh 
    delete &recveh; // remember to remove dynamically created object

    // existing code of this method
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You **can** add declaration of `struct knownVehicle ... ` in `WaveShortMessage.msg` - just after line `#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"` and before `}}`.

Comment: I tried to do as per your instruction but i got error message like:         MSGC: veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg
veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg:35: Error: unknown type 'knownVehicle' for field 'knownVeh' in 'WaveShortMessage'  . Also for receiving the waveshortmessage can I use the same code in OnData: as I have not use handleMessage.  Thank you.

Comment: You probably forgot the line `class noncobject knownVehicle`. I have inserted your structure to `WaveShortMessage.msg` file in my answer.

Comment: I have added a receiving code for `onData` method in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your for your help. I am still getting errors :     veins/modules/application/traci/TraCITestApp.cc:213:56: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'TraCITestApp::knownVehicle&' from expression of type 'knownVehicle'
               knownVehicle & recveh = wsm->getKnownVeh();   Also I put the send WaveShortMessage in     void TraCIDemo11p::sendMessage1(double theta) there is error with setknownVeh =>error: no matching function for call to 'EWaveShortMessage::setKnownVeh(TraCITestApp::knownVehicle&)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104254/discussion-between-jerzy-d-and-rakez).

Comment: For sending the message, can simply using     sendWSM(EWaveShortMessage* wsm) {
         if (isParking && !sendWhileParking) return;
        sendDelayedDown(wsm,individualOffset);
  } works for the sending the packet as well . I tried sending the packet using :     sendWSM1(EWaveShortMessage* packet) {
        if (isParking && !sendWhileParking) return;
        sendDelayedDown(packet ,individualOffset);

} but i got errors...